# Building Doxygen with clang and doxywizard

Tags: c++, clang, doxygen, doxygen-wizard

Because of my project I need to install this specific version of doxygen.
I am trying to install *doxygen(1.8.5)* with the flag's

```
--with-libclang
--with-doxywizard
```

The error's I get for **libclang** :

```
g++ -c -pipe -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wall -W -O2 -I../qtools -I../libmd5 -o ../objects/cite.o cite.cpp
g++ -c -pipe -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wall -W -O2 -I../qtools -I../libmd5 -o ../objects/clangparser.o clangparser.cpp
clangparser.cpp:6:27: fatal error: clang-c/Index.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [../objects/clangparser.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/doom/Downloads/doxygen-1.8.5/src'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/doom/Downloads/doxygen-1.8.5/src'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have obviously installed **clang(3.4)**.

```
Ubuntu clang version 3.4-1ubuntu3~precise1 (tags/RELEASE_34/final) (based on LLVM 3.4)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
```

Also I tried installing only with **doxywizard** and I still stuck with errors:

```
/usr/bin/make INSTALL=/usr/local MAN1DIR=man/man1 -C addon/doxywizard install
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/doom/Downloads/doxygen-1.8.5/addon/doxywizard'
/usr/bin/install -d /usr/local/bin
/usr/bin/install -m 755 ../../bin/doxywizard /usr/local/bin
/usr/bin/install: cannot stat `../../bin/doxywizard': No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [install] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/doom/Downloads/doxygen-1.8.5/addon/doxywizard'
make: *** [doxywizard_install] Error 2
```

I am not sure as what the problem is. Basic steps I followed are:

```
sudo ./configure --with-libclang --with-doxywizard
sudo make
sudo make install
```

Can anyone please let me know what the problem is ????

Comment: The current version of doxygen is 1.8.7, is there a special reason why you use 1.8.5?

Comment: @albert, yes I am working with a project whose documentation is written with *(1.8.5)*. I have also tried *(1.8.7)* with same flags and I am getting the same errors.

Comment: where is your libclang installed? From the configure script (1.8.7 around line 557) I can see that a number of paths are supported:   libclang_hdr_dir="/usr/include /usr/local/include /opt/local/include". When running ./configure --with-clang I also see the line:  Checking for libclang ... using header /usr/include/clang-c/Index.h and library /usr/lib/libclang.dll.a...